# How to request new driver for Intel 4th Generation?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

Does anyone know process to request the creation of a new ubuntu driver for this:
4th generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U Processor + Intel(R) HD Graphics(For 8GB Memory)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer than the [Intel official 4th Gen drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux) ?
You'd need to [register at their forum](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forums/general-discussion) and then post your request there.

Comment: It is not just the driver but kernel & other supporting software. Most of those updates are already in 13.10.